# Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object not found when using the predict function with an MCMC model

Tags: r, dataframe, glm, predict, mcmc

I am having issues getting the "newdata" argument in my predict function to work. In particular, when I run the code below (3rd line), I get the error: **Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'Risk' not found**.  I'm assuming that I either have a) formatting issues in the "newdata" dataframe or b) I am somehow entering the data incorrectly into the MCMCglmm model.

I am using a Markov-chain Monte Carlo glm to model my data (this is in the "MCMCglmm" package). Please note that for simplicity in the sake of this question, there are certain things I took out of the predict function, so the code below will not do what is statistically responsible (note I also get the same error when I DO add statistically responsible arguments).

```
ptsdMCMC.mod <- MCMCglmm(Risk ~ poly(Trial,2) * Group * Stimulus, family = "ordinal", data = ptsd.df, nitt = 100000)

newdata <- expand.grid(Trial=1:10, Stimulus=levels(ptsd.df$Stimulus), Group=levels(ptsd.df$Group))

ptsd.predict <- predict(ptsdMCMC.mod, newdata = newdata)
```

"Risk" is ordinal - with values of 0, 1, & 2

"Group" is nominal - 3 different groups

"Trial" is ordinal - there are 10 trials

"Stimulus" is ordinal - there are 6 different stimuli in increasing size

Each participant has a value for each Trial*Stimulus combo (i.e. there are 60 total observations per participant).

**Do you see anything wrong with the formatting of my "newdata" data frame, where it would not work within the context of the predict function and produce this error?** If not, I believe that narrows it down to problems with the MCMCglmm model estimation. Do also note that if I take out the "newdata" argument, the predict function works. However, it estimates data points based on the original dataset ptsd.df, which includes estimation based on subject ID, which I don't want (also, it's not even part of the original model).

Thanks!

Comment: It would be easier to help if you provided a reproducible example with sample input data so we can actually run the code to see what's going on. Maybe use a sample dataset from the package help pages.